# Spring boot server all shutdown at the same time for unknown reason

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have a bunch of spring boot servers and they are different code base (but all cloned from the same base)

They all went down last night, at slightly different time. When I looked at the log, it didn't say much. Here is the log

```
2021-08-06 06:22:09.735  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'threadPoolTaskScheduler'
2021-08-06 06:22:09.747  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-06 06:22:09.750  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-08-06 06:22:09.761  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Here is the log from another project we have

```
2021-08-06 06:36:39.317  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-08-06 06:36:39.324  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-08-06 06:36:39.329  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-06 06:36:39.341  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-08-06 06:36:39.354  INFO 1 --- [       Thread-3] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

What could be the reason and how do I troubleshoot this?

The springboot runs inside a docker image, running on ubuntu.

The servers were able to be rebooted immediately without issue.

Comment: Was the Docker container still running?

Comment: Does not appear to be. I guess you are right, maybe this is a docker question

Comment: I'll be following this as this happened to us a few weeks ago. But instead of our Tomcat instance (In Ubuntu), it was our Database that stopped. Our best guess was something about idle processes being killed by the OS but didn't investigate through. We have a ComputeEngine in GCP.